# React event object

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React project but I've encountered an issue.
I don't know why event object is not passed by onSubmit.

```
const SearchBar = () =>{

     const test = (e) =>{
        console.log(e);
     }
     return (
        <form className="ui form" onSubmit={()=>test()}>
            <div className="inline field">                
                <input className="myinput" type="text" style={{width: '85%'}}/>
                <button className="ui primary button"  type="submit">button</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass event in your onSubmit like below-

```
<form className="ui form" onSubmit={(event)=>test(event)}>
```

Comment: or even shorter `onSubmit={test}`

Comment: @molamk way should be preferred since you should avoid using arrow function inside the `render()` method